# Swift- application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

Tags: ios, swift

What does it mean to put something in my application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:. And how do i do it in swift?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a boiler plate method provided in your iOS project's `AppDelegate` file defined as

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch. Here you can out the code you want.

    return true
}
```

If you want to handle cases such as if app is opened by a URL or by remote notification then you might want to put your code before `return`.

If the app can handle the url then keep the return value `true` otherwise `false`. In case of push notification, the return value would anyway be ignored.

Hope this would help.

Comment: so far so good - what is it for? You should include at least a little bit of actual useful information in your answer.

Comment: Yes, thanks for answering

Answer (score 4):

This function gets invoked right before your app is fully loaded. If you're familiar with jQuery, it's sort of like $(document).ready(function() {}) Below is a link to documentation from Apple on how to implement this function:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Answer (score 0):

`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is part of the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol, which is responsible with handling different changes over your application state. You can find out more about this method and about the app delegate protocol in the Apple documentation from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:). I strongly recommend reading it before moving forward.

You should get the below code automatically generated by Xcode if you create a brand new Swift iOS project:

```
@UIApplicationMain 
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    // ...

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
```

You can place the code you need into that method, or add the method to your `UIApplicationDelegate` if it's not already there.